# Calculating probabilities from a joint density

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Suppose the rvs $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density $f(x,y)= 2(x+y)$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$ calculate: $\Pr(X<0.5, y<0.5)$

I have attempted to do this two ways, one which involved integrating the joint density twice wrt to $dx$ and $dy$ respectively, using the same limits $(0, 0.5)$ both times this gave me an output of $0.25$. I feel this is not correct because I have not considered the upper limit of $x$ on $y$.

In the second method, I changed the limits. wrt $dx$ I used the limits $(y, 0.5)$ and wrt to $dy$ I used the limits $(0, x)$ and integrated twice as normal. This led to an output of a function in terms of $x$: $$\frac x4+\frac{x^2}2-x^3$$

Which I am not convinced is correct either as it is a function not a value, any advice?

Comment: Integrating with the same limits $(0,0.5)$ is incorrect because of the very reason you state. You are including area that isn't in the sample space.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is

$$P(X<\frac{1}{2};Y<\frac{1}{2})=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg[\int_{0}^{x}2(x+y)dy\Bigg]dx=$$

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x^2+x^2) dx=\frac{3}{24}=\frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: Thank you for this, would this also be the same as Pr(x<0.5), as my calculation seems to be the exact same procedure?